# WordPress: Populate list field with WooCommerce products in Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I want to let users select products in a form.
To do that, I need to dynamically populate a form with published WooCommerce produts.

I found a solution to populate a select field with WooCommerce produts.
But the user should be able to select a quantity per product. Therefore I need to use a list field and populate the cells of the list field.

Here's how the list field looks:

[image]

The SKU and the title fields should be populated dynamically.
And the quantity field is for the user to fill.

Here's my code to populate a select field with WooCommerce product data:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_5', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_5', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_5', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_5', 'populate_posts' );
function populate_posts( $form ) {

    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

        if ( $field->type != 'select' || strpos( $field->cssClass, 'populate-posts' ) === false ) {
            continue;
        }

        // you can add additional parameters here to alter the posts that are retrieved
        // more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
        $posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1&post_status=publish&post_type=product' );

        $choices = array();

        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            $choices[] = array( 'text' => $post->post_title, 'value' => $post->post_title );
        }

        // update 'Select a Post' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be
        $field->placeholder = 'Select a product';
        $field->choices = $choices;

    }

    return $form;
}
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to populate the cells of a list field dynamically.

I found an example how to populate a list field: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_value_parameter_name/#list-field

But I couldn't figure out how to combine these two snippets :/

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_list', 'populate_list' );
function populate_list( $value ) {
  $list_array = array(
            array(
                'Column 1' => 'row1col1',
                'Column 2' => 'row1col2',
                'Column 3' => 'row1col3',
            ),
            array(
                'Column 1' => 'row2col1',
                'Column 2' => 'row2col2',
                'Column 3' => 'row2col3'
            ),
  );
    return $list_array;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, here's my working code.

With some big help from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61098114/1788961

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_list', 'populate_list' );
function populate_list( $value ) {

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $statuses = array('publish', 'draft');

    // Args on the main query for WC_Product_Query
    $args = [
        'status'    => $statuses,
        'orderby'   => 'name',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'limit'     => -1,
    ];

    $vendor_products = wc_get_products($args);

    $list_array = array();

    foreach ($vendor_products as $key => $product) {

        if ($product->get_type() == "variable") {

            // Args on product variations query for a variable product using a WP_Query
            $args2 = array( 
                'post_parent' => $product->get_id(), 
                'post_type'   => 'product_variation', 
                'orderby'     => array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC', 'ID' => 'ASC' ), 
                'fields'      => 'ids', 
                'post_status' => $statuses, 
                'numberposts' => -1, 
            ); 

            foreach ( get_posts( $args2 ) as $child_id ) {
                // get an instance of the WC_Variation_product Object
                $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id ); 

                if ( ! $variation || ! $variation->exists() ) {
                    continue;
                }

                $list_array[] = array(
                    'SKU'      => $variation->get_sku(),
                    'Name'     => $product->get_name() . " - " . $child_id,
                );
            }

        } else {

            $list_array[] = array(
                'SKU'      => $product->get_sku(),
                'Name'     => $product->get_name(),
            );

        }

    }

    return $list_array;

}
```

Comment: Good stuff. What was your use-case?

Comment: I want to let product vendors (WC Vendors) add some informations about their products via form. Therefore I need to show only their products in the form.

Answer (score 1):

Just modified your code a little to make first column as a select field and dynamically populate the product names to not have a long list being displayed.

```
add_filter( 'gform_column_input_4_11_1', 'set_column', 10, 5 );
function set_column( $input_info, $field, $column, $value, $form_id ) {
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  $statuses = array('publish', 'draft');

  // Args on the main query for WC_Product_Query
  $args = [
      'status'    => $statuses,
      'orderby'   => 'name',
      'order'     => 'ASC',
      'limit'     => -1,
  ];

  $vendor_products = wc_get_products($args);

  $choices = array();

  foreach ($vendor_products as $key => $product) {

      if ($product->get_type() == "variable") {

          // Args on product variations query for a variable product using a WP_Query
          $args2 = array( 
              'post_parent' => $product->get_id(), 
              'post_type'   => 'product_variation', 
              'orderby'     => array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC', 'ID' => 'ASC' ), 
              'fields'      => 'ids', 
              'post_status' => $statuses, 
              'numberposts' => -1, 
          ); 

          foreach ( get_posts( $args2 ) as $child_id ) {
              // get an instance of the WC_Variation_product Object
              $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id ); 

              if ( ! $variation || ! $variation->exists() ) {
                  continue;
              }
      

      $choices[] = array( 'text' => $product->get_name() . " - " . $child_id, 'value' => $product->get_name() . " - " . $child_id );
          }

      } else {
    $choices[] = array( 'text' => $product->get_name(), 'value' => $product->get_name() );


      }

  }

  return array( 'type' => 'select', 'choices' => $choices );
}
```